# My shortcut key will not allow me to run a message box

Tags: vba, excel

Previous versions of this code had no message box, which sometimes resulted in the wrong workbook being closed. I added an okcancel message box to keep this from happening, but the message box doesn't show up when I use a shortcut key to open it. What am I missing?

```
Sub openerQuick()

    Dim myfile As String
    Dim clientID As String
    Dim PDSfilename As String
    Dim myopener As Variant

    clientID = ActiveCell
    PDSfilename = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
    myfile = "N:\DOWNLOAD\FILEDIR\" & clientID & "\original\" & PDSfilename
    Set wbOpener = Workbooks.Open(myfile)

    If MsgBox("Okay to close?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean a shortcut key to trigger the macro?  Add a `Debug.Print "words"` line before the `If` statement. Then trigger your macro via the shortcut key.  Then check the Immediate Window (CTRL+G when in the VBEditor) and see if you see "words".

Comment: I did that and do not see "words".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the `MsgBox` itself has anything to do with losing the macro shortcut key.

Shortcut keys are defined by a hidden member attribute value, and the VBE has a tendency to lose member attributes when you rewrite a method's signature, or rewrite a module*; it's possible that modifying the code caused the previously existing attribute to somehow get lost.

- Remove the module from the project, pick "Yes" when prompted whether to export or not
- Open the exported file in <s>Notepad++</s> *your favorite text editor*
- Locate the procedure
- Add the attribute if it's not there
- Save the file if it was changed, re-import into the project

The member attribute should look something like this:

```
Public Sub OpenerQuick()
    Attribute OpenerQuick.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = "A\n14"
    '...code....
End Sub
```

That exact attribute associates <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to the macro; change the `A` for whichever letter rocks your boat to change the shortcut.

When you record a macro in Excel and specify `A` for a shortcut key, the macro recorder automatically adds this hidden attribute for you.

---

* [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com)'s module rewriters have that very problem and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, you've really helped me. On a side note, surely there is no such favorite text editor besides Notepad++ (since my current job has opened my eyes to it).

Answer (score 0):

In a module write the following 2 subs:

```
Public Sub OpenerQuick()
    If MsgBox("Okay to close?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub

Public Sub InitiateMe()
    Application.OnKey "{a}", "OpenerQuick"
End Sub
```

Run only `InitiateMe`. Now, when you press <kbd>a</kbd>, `InitiateMe` would be triggered.